# How can I move postgresql data to another directory on Ubuntu over Amazon EC2?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, permissions, amazon-ec2

We've been running postgresql 8.4 for quite some time. As with any database, we are slowly reaching our threshold for space. I added another 8 GB EBS drive and mounted it to our instance and configured it to work properly on a directory called /files

Within /files, I manually created

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe all postgresql data is stored in /var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main

I backed up the database and I ran sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql stop. This stops the postgresql server. I tried to copy and paste the contents of /var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main into the /files directory but that turned out be a HUGE MESS! due to file permissions. I had to go in and chmod the contents of that folder just so that I could copy and paste them. Some files did not copy fully because of root permissions. I modified the data_directory parameter in postgresql.conf to point to the files directory

```
 data_directory = '/files/postgresql/main'
```

and I ran sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart and the server failed to start. Again probably due to permission issues. Amazon EC2 only allows you to access the service as ubuntu by default. You can only access root from within the terminal which makes everything a lot more complicated.

Is there a much cleaner and more efficient step by step way of doing this?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Stop the server.

Copy the datadir while retaining permissions - use `cp -aRv`.

Then (easiest, as it avoids the need to modify initscripts) just move the old datadir aside and symlink the old path to the new location.

Comment: Hello, could you explain what you mean by "move the old datadir aside"? you mean, just remove it or copy it to some backup folder? and: which data directory do you mean? the whole folder that is returned by `show data_directory;`?

Comment: Rename it, so you don't lose anything if it turns out it was important after all.

Comment: The symlinlk ideas is not bad but neither perfect because it requires you keep around the old datadir location.

Comment: Nice tip! Just to mention that after creating the symlink, we need to change ownership to it (setting postgres as the owner and group).

Comment: I tried a bunch of different things and the easiest and cleanest way I found to 'stop the server' was this: 'sudo service postgresql stop' as 'ubuntu' if you are using an ubuntu AMI. Otherwise, shutting down the server can be difficult on ec2 due to requiring the sudo password via the postgres user/owner of the postgres processes.

Comment: To quote [Tom Lane at the PostgreSQL user list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/11517.1389366376@sss.pgh.pa.us): "That symlink doesn't sound like a terribly good idea.  You should customize
the service file to specify a correct PGDATA path, instead."  Seriously, if you are going to take the time to make a symlink and change permissions, why not instead just take that time to do it the right way?  Correct your PGDATA path instead of making a symlink.

Answer (score 16):

Thanks for the accepted answer. Instead of the symlink you can also use a [bind mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount). That way it is independent from the file system. If you want to use a dedicated hard drive for the database you can also [mount it normally](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72125/correct-way-to-mount-a-hard-drive). to the data directory.

I did the latter. Here are my steps if someone needs a reference. I ran this as a script on many AWS instances.

```
# stop postgres server
sudo service postgresql stop

# create new filesystem in empty hard drive
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdb

# mount it
mkdir /tmp/pg
sudo mount /dev/xvdb /tmp/pg/

# copy the entire postgres home dir content
sudo cp -a /var/lib/postgresql/. /tmp/pg

# mount it to the correct directory
sudo umount /tmp/pg
sudo mount /dev/xvdb /var/lib/postgresql/

# see if it is mounted 
mount | grep postgres

# add the mount point to fstab
echo "/dev/xvdb /var/lib/postgresql ext4 rw 0 0" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab

# when database is in use, observe that the correct disk is being used
watch -d grep xvd /proc/diskstats
```

Answer (score 1):

A clarification. It is the particular AMI that you used that sets ubuntu as the default user, this may not apply to other AMIs.

In essence if you are trying move data manually, you will probably need to do so as the root user, and then make sure its available to whatever user postgres is running with.

You also do have the option of snapshotting the volume and increasing the size of the a volume created from the snapshot. Then you could replace the volume on your instance with the new volume (You probably will have to resize the partition to take advantage of all the space).